# Send multiple photos from Room with Retrofit (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit, android-room

I have an app the stores photos with Room in the database I store a image in a byte[].

I have an activity where when I press the button upload the images through Retrofit but when I start to upload, the app throws an error.

Here is the code of the function to upload the images;

```
for (int i = 0; i < evidences.size(); i++) {
    order = evidences.get(i).getMobmx();
    ticketEv = evidences.get(i).getTicketEv();

    Toast.makeText(this, "MOBMX: " + order, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    File filesDir = this.getFilesDir();
    File photo = new File(filesDir, "" + order + ".jpeg");

    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(photo);
        fos.write(ticketEv);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), photo);
    MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", photo.getName(), requestFile);

    apiService.uploadPod(getString(R.string.uploadPodOfflinePetition), body, RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), order))
        .enqueue(new Callback<UserData>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserData> call, Response<UserData> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        try {
                            processResult(response.body().getMsg(), response.body().getData());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(OnlineEvidenceActivity.this, "Error procesando la respuesta del servidor, por favor intente de nuevo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    try {
                        String erroResp = response.errorBody().string();
                        Log.i("ERROR", erroResp);
                        processError(erroResp);
                    } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(OnlineEvidenceActivity.this, "Error al procesar respuesta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserData> call, Throwable t) {
                //RequestFailHandler.handleFail(OnlineEvidenceActivity.this, t);
                Log.e("ERROREVIDENCIA", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
}
```

Here is the function when the response is successful:

```
private void processResult(String msg, Object data) {
    StatusPODS statusPODS = new StatusPODS();
    if (msg.equals("ok")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Procesar evidencia", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        statusPODS.setMobmx(order);
        statusPODS.setStatus("Exitoso");
        evidenceDAO.insertStatus(statusPODS);

        //evidenceDAO.deleteRow(order);
    } else if (msg.equals("warning")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "" + data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        statusPODS.setMobmx(order);
        statusPODS.setStatus("Warning");
        evidenceDAO.insertStatus(statusPODS);
        //evidenceDAO.deleteRow(order);
    } else {
        //Error
        Toast.makeText(this, "" + data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        statusPODS.setMobmx(order);
        statusPODS.setStatus("Error");
        evidenceDAO.insertStatus(statusPODS);
        //evidenceDAO.deleteRow(order);
    }
}
```

This is the Service endpoint:

```
@Multipart
@POST("mobile/uploadpodoffline")
Call<UserData> uploadPod(@Header("petition") String petition,
                         @Part MultipartBody.Part image,
                         @Part ("order") RequestBody order);
```

And finally this is the error when upload the first image:

```
HTTP FAILED: java.net.ProtocolException: expected 422764 bytes but received 425984
```

Any solution to upload the images creating a new File and send through the for loop with retrofit (?)

Thanks

Comment: You are saying that the `RequestBody` is `text/plain`. Elsewhere in your code, you refer to the file with a `.jpeg` extension, and your question indicates that these are images. If so, try switching the MIME type in your `RequestBody` to be `image/jpeg`.

Comment: @CommonsWare No, the petition is a MultiPart Body and it sends a part Image and a part Text. The text/plain is for the other value of MultiPart

Comment: Ah, sorry! I misread that. Another thing you could try: between `fos.flush();` and `fos.close();`, add `fos.getFD().sync()`. That ensures that all the data is written to disk, despite any caching that might be done at the filesystem level.